# Inject a String into a Message Driven Bean

Tags: dependency-injection, message-driven-bean, deployment-descriptor, ejb-jar.xml

I want to configure the behaviour of one of my mdbs with string. i created a setMessageType method and want to inject the identifier string into the mdb by configuration in the ejb-jar (deployment descriptor).

I know how do declare a bean in the ejb-jar but how do i control dependency injection?

Greetings,

Laures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

funny i never go an answer to this questions.

```
<message-driven>
    <ejb-name>mymdb</ejb-name>
    <ejb-class>net.something.MyMDBClass</ejb-class>
    <activation-config>
        <activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
            <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Topic</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>

            <activation-config-property-value>i.listen.here</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
    </activation-config>
    <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>MessageType</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>myconfigstring</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>
</message-driven>
```

Comment: ... and how does one access this?! Apparently with JNDI on java:comp/env/MessageType ...